# Mass Connector Health Plans and new employment

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, massachusetts, affordable-care-act

I'm currently self-employed and I have insurance through Massachusetts Health Connector, which is what the Affordable Care Act is called in Massachusetts.  I have a good income level so I don't qualify for any financial assistance.

I have been offered a job that includes health insurance.  If I take this job, do I lose my insurance from Mass Connector?  In other words, is it a continuing requirement of Mass Connector Health plans that I don't have other health insurance available to me?

It is hard to find info online because most search results relate to financial assistance for low-income folks and that doesn't apply to my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Income change is new information that you may have to report. An employer offer of health insurance is new information that you may have to report. See this [MassHealth link](https://www.mass.gov/how-to/report-changes-in-your-information-to-masshealth-for-individuals-and-families-and-people).

As you mentioned, you have no subsidy, so you may be able to keep your current insurance.

Comment: @gaefan Also keep in mind you will no longer be able to deduct your premiums through the Massachusetts Health Connector (since you're no longer self-employed), but you will be able to deduct premiums for your employer's health insurance. And they should provide some sort of subsidy.

Answer (score -1):

You can ask your potential new employer several questions related to their employment benefits:

- Do they offer health care, and can they give you information about the plan? You are interested in costs, deductibles, co-pays and the like. Some companies have great plans, others not so great plans; some companies pick up none of the cost, some split the costs, others pay the entire premium. They might only give you a one page document, but ask if they have a more detailed document.
- If the plan they offer is bad, or if your cost is expensive, you can ask if they will offer an additional benefit if you decline the coverage. People decline coverage because their spouse has a better plan, or they have one as retired military. I have known companies to give extra vacation days, or pay a monthly stipend if you decline the coverage.
- Other medical things you might be interested in are Health savings account, and Flexible savings accounts. Not all companies offer them, and they have specific rules you have to understand. But you should ask.

Added Information:

So can you keep your plan purchased through the exchange?

Yes you can keep your plan from the exchange, if you want to. The goal of the affordable care act was to get health insurance coverage for everybody. A person/family can get coverage from their employer, or from an exchange, or by contacting an insurance company that sells policies in your state.

One key part of the ACA was to set standards. All plans offered in the exchange meet the standards.

You can pick your insurance based on costs, options, doctors in network...But the cheapest option is likely to be a policy through your employer, but you need to check with your employer.

Comment: Sorry that my question was unclear.  I just tried to improve it.  I want to know if I am able to keep my current health plan after I have a job offer that includes insurance.

Comment: @gaefan sure you can keep your Mass Connect health plan.  I can't imagine that it would be cheaper than your new company's plan.